# How to push array of objects to a new array variable inside another object inside array by value?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have 2 array that consist object :

```
a = 
[
 {
  id: 105647,
  name: 'name1'
 },
 {
  id: 105941,
  name: 'name2'
 },
 {
  id: 106177,
  name: 'name3'
 }
]

b = 
[
 [
  {
   id: 105647,
   transactionDate: '2022-03-21',
   order: 1
  },
  {
   id: 105647,
   transactionDate: '2022-03-22',
   order: 2
  }
 ],
 [
  {
   id: 106177,
   transactionDate: '2022-03-24',
   order: 1
  },
 ]
]
```

As you can see, that in `b` is not always have data for each `id` in variable `a`.

And my desired output would be

```
a = 
[
 {
  id: 105647,
  name: 'name1',
  dataB:
   [
    {
     id: 105647,
     transactionDate: '2022-03-21',
     order: 1
    },
    {
     id: 105647,
     transactionDate: '2022-03-22',
     order: 2
    }
   ]
 },
 {
  id: 105941,
  name: 'name2'
 },
 {
  id: 106177,
  name: 'name3',
  dataB: 
   [
    {
     id: 106177,
     transactionDate: '2022-03-24',
     order: 1
    },
   ]
  }
]
```

the `b` variable should be pushed to new variable `dataB` inside object of array on variable `a`. And if no dataB exist on `a` it would not create `dataB` on `a` / create the `dataB` but with empty array.

I was already try with some

```
for (let i = 0; i<a.length; i++) {
  a[i]['dataB'] = b[i]
}
```

the result is not pushed by `id`, but by index. The problem is `b` not always have data for each `id` in variable `a`. And what i'm trying was not what i looking for.

Please ask me if you need more information if it's still not enough to solve that case.

Comment: The general process to solve problems like this is to create an object that uses the ID values as keys. Then when you loop over the other array, it's easy to find the object with the same ID.

Comment: To add on, if the `values` corresponding to the ID keys (from `b`) are arrays, then when you `.map` over `a`, things become much more easier to transform elements of `a` as per your target structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your goal is to **modify a**, as opposed to creating a new array, you can use `Array#forEach` and `Array#filter` methods as follows:

```js
const a = [ { id: 105647, name: 'name1' }, { id: 105941, name: 'name2' }, { id: 106177, name: 'name3' } ]; 
const b = [ [ { id: 105647, transactionDate: '2022-03-21', order: 1 }, { id: 105647, transactionDate: '2022-03-22', order: 2 } ], [ { id: 106177, transactionDate: '2022-03-24', order: 1 }, ] ];

a.forEach((elA,i) => {
    const others = b.filter(elB => elB.every(o => o.id === elA.id)).flat();
    a[i] = others.length ? {...elA, dataB: others} : elA;
});

console.log( a );
```

Since in `b` the items are already grouped by `id`, `Array#find` may be a better method, and will not need the use of `Array#flat`:

```js
const a = [ { id: 105647, name: 'name1' }, { id: 105941, name: 'name2' }, { id: 106177, name: 'name3' } ]; 
const b = [ [ { id: 105647, transactionDate: '2022-03-21', order: 1 }, { id: 105647, transactionDate: '2022-03-22', order: 2 } ], [ { id: 106177, transactionDate: '2022-03-24', order: 1 }, ] ];

a.forEach((elA,i) => {
    const others = b.find(elB => elB.every(o => o.id === elA.id));
    a[i] = others ? {...elA, dataB: others} : elA;
    /*OR: you can replace the above one line with the following 3
    if( others ) {
        a[i].dataB = others;
    }*/
});

console.log( a );
```

Comment: iwas trying using your code, but it's not working. My mistake, the ```b``` data actually contains 2 [] inside, i was updated on my post. Is your code can still work on that format data like that ? thanks

Comment: Take a look at the updated code.

Comment: thankss, it's perfectly work like i would

Answer (score 1):

loop thought `a` array,

on each iteration find all matches

if array is not empty - assign it to new field `dataB`

```js
    const a = 
    [
     {
      id: 105647,
      name: 'name1'
     },
     {
      id: 105941,
      name: 'name2'
     },
     {
      id: 106177,
      name: 'name3'
     }
    ]

    const b = 
[
 [
  {
   id: 105647,
   transactionDate: '2022-03-21',
   order: 1
  },
  {
   id: 105647,
   transactionDate: '2022-03-22',
   order: 2
  }
 ],
 [
  {
   id: 106177,
   transactionDate: '2022-03-24',
   order: 1
  },
 ]
];

    const result = a.map(i => {
    const foundTrancactions = b.flat().filter(el => el.id === i.id);
return {...i, ...(foundTrancactions?.length ? {dataB: foundTrancactions} : {})}
    })

    console.log(result)
```

**UPDATE**

- have changed `b` array
- added `flat()` for `b`

Comment: You may need to notify that `a` will no longer remain what it was. After `console.log(result)`, you may do a `console.log(a)` to observe that it has also changed. This is because `i` is being mutated.

Comment: I have updated, thanks

Comment: i was using your code, but the ```dataB``` is not show

Comment: ohh my bad, the ```b``` data was different. I was updating my code above, there's double [] actually on ```b```,  how to make your code working on data like that ? thanks @shutsman

Comment: @user18605090 I have updated answer, simply need to add `flat()` before `filter()`

Comment: @user18605090 hope my answer helps you and you will mark it as correct as it was the first answer))

Answer (score 0):

This solution is non-mutating and employs the idea shared by [Barmar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1491895/barmar) in comments above.

**Code Snippet**

```js
const getTransformedArray = (orig, delta) => {
  // first, construct a key-value pair using "b" array (called "delta" here)
  const deltaMap = delta
    .flat()       // since "b" is nested, use ".flat()" to flatten it
    .reduce(
      (acc, itm) => ({
        ...acc,         // retain existing results from "acc" (accumulator)
        [itm.id]: (
          acc[itm.id] || []     // if "itm.id" already exists, keep its array
        ).concat([{...itm}])    // append the current "itm"
      }),
      {}                // "acc" is initially set to empty object "{}"
    );
  // now, iterate through "a" array (named "orig" here)
  return orig.map(
    ({id, name}) => ({    // de-structure to directly access "id", "name" props
      id, name,           // retain "id", "name"
      ...(                // add new prop "dataB" only if it's in deltaMap
        id in deltaMap
        ? { dataB: deltaMap[id] }
        : {}              // if no matching "id" in "deltaMap", don't add "dataB"
      )
    })
  );
};


const a = 
[
 {
  id: 105647,
  name: 'name1'
 },
 {
  id: 105941,
  name: 'name2'
 },
 {
  id: 106177,
  name: 'name3'
 }
]

const b = [
 [
  {
   id: 105647,
   transactionDate: '2022-03-21',
   order: 1
  },
  {
   id: 105647,
   transactionDate: '2022-03-22',
   order: 2
  }
 ],
 [
  {
   id: 106177,
   transactionDate: '2022-03-24',
   order: 1
  },
 ]
];

// invoke the transform function
console.log('transformed array: ', getTransformedArray(a, b));

// display "a" and "b" arrays to show those were not mutated
console.log('original a: ', a);
console.log('original b: ', b);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0 }
```

**Explanation**

Inline comments provided in the snippet above.

Comment: my bad, the ```b``` data was actually has 2 [], i was updated on my post. That's why your code still not working on me. Can you provide with my updates ?

Comment: Just needed to add one ".flat()" in the method. It's updated.